# Setting different user priviledges for an android studio app

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-studio, mamp

I am creating an attendance monitoring app using Android Studio and MAMP server. I have the same MYSQL database connected to both apps. Initially I was creating an app for students and another app for staff. However I think this is not the best way to go about this. Is there any way to set different user privileges so I can just create one mobile app that will give users access to different pages within the app? Thank you

Comment: This is design issue on your part. If you have a way to distinguish between your two different user types you will be able to follow different logic paths through your app

Comment: How do I go about doing this? Do I keep two different tables in my database for students and staff?

Answer (score 0):

In response to your question and comments. You should have a single table for user and in that table have a column which stores the privilege level of that user. Then for each user when they log into the system you can check what privilege level they have and load the correct resources.